# MSBuild:Compile directives in .NET MAIU project file

Tags: maui

In the project file of my .NET MAUI app, I see a section that contains `MSBuild:Compile` directives for each and every view in my app -- see below:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <MauiXaml Update="Views\Home\Home.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
   </MauiXaml>
   <MauiXaml Update="Views\Home\Page2.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
   </MauiXaml>
   <MauiXaml Update="Views\Settings\Settings.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
   </MauiXaml>
</ItemGroup>
```

What exactly is the purpose of this section and is it necessary? It looks like they're instructing the views to be compiled but are they necessary? Would they not get compiled without these directives?

Comment: I'm told by Allan Ritchie that I don't need to have them in the project file. The IDE inserts them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately all XAML needs to be compiled. When it happens matters. It can either be pre-compiled at design time or build time, or compiled at runtime. Obviously if compilation happens at runtime, it can slow the app down due to the time it takes to compile the XAML so generally pre-compiling XAML is preferred.

The `<Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>` tells **MSBuild** to generate the C# for the XAML page every time the XAML file is saved, saving time to do the same during project build. The IDE does insert it by default because the engineering team feel it is beneficial to most as it will  reduce build time when debugging. You are of course free to remove the elements if you do not want that behavior.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Hi Liqun, does this matter when in a maui library project? Is there a way to add all xaml files to be compiled when save by default? Thanks